# matplotlib how to loop through each ax in subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to visualize 10 different things on all different figure.

```
figure, ((ax1, ax2), (ax3, ax4), (ax5, ax6), (ax7, ax8), (ax9, ax10)) = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=5)
figure.set_size_inches(17,8)

for i, age_g in enumerate(age_cat):
    group = total_usage_df.loc[(total_usage_df.age_group == age_g) & (total_usage_df.day_of_week <= 4)]
    sns.distplot(group.rent_hour, ax=)
```

On the last line I do not know how to loop through all ax from 1 ~10.

I am hoping to pass a list of [ax1, ax2, etc...] so I can loop through them:

```
lst = [ax1, ax2, ax3, ax4, ax5, ax6, ax7, ax8, ax9, ax10]
figure, (lst) = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=5)
figure.set_size_inches(17,8)

for i, age_g in zip(lst, age_cat):
    group = total_usage_df.loc[(total_usage_df.age_group == age_g) & (total_usage_df.day_of_week <= 4)]
    sns.distplot(group.rent_hour, ax=i)
```

something like this however it outputs:

```
NameError: name 'ax1' is not defined
```

how can I loop through each ax1 ~ ax10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you should use `ravel` or `flatten`:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=5)

# loop through the axes, one by one
for ax, age in zip(axes.ravel(), age_cat):
    group = ...
    sns.displot(...)
```

Comment: I don't need to add 10 ax element? creating axes and assgining nrows, ncols automatically creates it?

Comment: As you already accepted the answer: Yes, that’s what `ply.subplots` does :).